# how to set default node read location for extension in vs-code?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, nvm

**Pre-problem**

I install npm and node using nvm, so that make my npm and node location in directory

npm `/home/putrapc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/npm`
node `/home/putrapc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node`

all i install in stable version

**The problem**

I start using vs-code and there is always error notification that annoy me, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqF5c.png)

I realize that problem because the extension in vs-code like jsHint, flow, Javascript standard style, etc doesn't read any of my npm package properly. Yes it cause the directory isn't  correct, how to change default read directory in vs-code ?

My eslint directory

`/home/putrapc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/eslint -> /home/putrapc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js`

i had eslint installed as package, but the vs-code still didn't read it. How to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was encountering similar issues with VS Code extensions encountering issues when trying to run Node with error messages such as

> /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

The simplest solution I found to this is to **use a terminal to start Visual Studio in the folder that you're trying to open from**

This can be done by **navigating to the folder** you're trying to open in Code, **opening a terminal** there, and typing in

```
$ code .
```

The above behaviour seems to happen because NVM sets its own variables for the node location and that is what is used by default in your terminal session. You can check these using

```
env | grep NVM
```

This returned the following for me

```
NVM_DIR=/home/saikat/.nvm
NVM_CD_FLAGS=
NVM_BIN=/home/saikat/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin
```

Also, trying to get the current Node location using *which* returns the following

```
$ which node
/home/saikat/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin/node
```

When starting Visual Studio Code from anywhere apart from the terminal, the above NVM variables don't get set and hence the extensions try to find node at the default location */usr/bin/env* and are unable to find it there and hence fail

Comment: Been forget about this, but yeah actually your solution works. I tried that before but forget to answer my question. Thanks.